# How took multimple unknown name inputs from laravel request

Tags: laravel

Hello i have request with unknown name inputs like Game234_3v3player_3 etc. Due to all inputs are nullable and game number is unknown i validated it like this:

```
$request->validate([
        '*_2v2player_*' => [
            'exists:users,name',
            'nullable',
        ],
        '*_2v2enemyPlayer_*' => [
            'exists:enemy_players_list,nickname',
            'nullable',
        ],
        '*_3v3player_*' => [
            'exists:users,name',
            'nullable',
        ],
        '*_3v3enemyPlayer_*' => [
            'exists:enemy_players_list,nickname',
            'nullable',
```

In validation, this works. But, i want to store parts of request in variable. What i tried is:

```
        $data = $request->only([
        '*_1v1enemyPlayer_*',
        '*.2v2enemyPlayer.*',
        '*3v3enemyPlayer*',
        ]);
```

Etc...
However, it returns empty array in every way in this example */*./*_. With dots, dashes etc, etc.
How i can then took into variable only few request atributes with unknown names?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand your request keys with `array_keys($request->all())`.

Finally you can decide which key you are looking for.

Comment: It wont help becouse i want take only inputs with *enemyPlayers* name, and becouse other inputs are nullable indexing it is not helping. There is more inputs than in this example,  I cant pass in array_keys() "*enemyPlayers*" as argument. It doesnt work.

Comment: Well it helps finnaly but in different way ;)

Comment: @WNR Im so happy that helped you, good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok did it other way.

```
    $enemyPlayers = [];

    $requestArray = array_keys($request->all());
    foreach($requestArray as $player)
    {
        if (str_contains($player, 'enemyPlayer')) {
            array_push($enemyPlayers, $player);
        }
    }
```